# Generalisation of Fatou-Julia theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, fractals, complex-dynamics, topological-dynamics

In an already answered [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142294/does-every-basin-of-attraction-contain-a-critical-point) regarding the Fatou-Julia theorem (every basin of attraction contains a critical point), I saw that a user stated:

> There are some other situations where an analogous theorem applies.
> For instance, if you define everything correctly it holds for
> nonivertible holomorphic maps on higher dimensional projective spaces
> as well, but this is harder.

Does someone know where to find a proof for this?
Specifically, I want to use it on a function $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ with nice properties.

Thank you.

Comment: I am extremely skeptical that something like this will work if your map is not holomorphic